# File.exists giving a null reference exception instead of returning false. c#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, system.io.file

```
if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/users/" + Input.GetComponent<Text>().text + ".dat"))
```

This line always causes a null reference exception instead of returning false when it cannot find the file.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't, the code within gives the null reference exception, please debug your code to work out why

Comment: Extract `Application.persistentDataPath` and `Input.GetComponent<Text>()` out of the call and check values for both in the debugger.

Comment: When I clicked on the error message it gave the error for this line of code, and none of the other code even triggers without going through this if statement

Comment: once again, `File.Exists` is **not** the problem, the code inside it is

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` happens when you try to access a member (property, method, field) of an object that's `null`. Therefore, one of these things is `null` => `Application`, `Input`, or `GetComponent<Text>()`

Answer (score 0):

`File.Exists` is not problem. Think about fixing your code like this

```
    if (Application.persistentDataPath != null && Input != null && Input.GetComponent<Text>() != null && Input.GetComponent<Text>().text != null)
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/users/" + Input.GetComponent<Text>().text + ".dat"))
```

Comment: @RufusL I have just fixed them. Suggestion in the comments is enought for this question but I see asker doesn't really understand problem

Comment: Your last condition should be `Input.GetComponent<Text>() != null`.